# Getting mysql query result from function, TypeError: callback is not a function

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to do MySQL query inside some function with callback, getting an error:

> TypeError: callback is not a function

```
function getContent(lang, callback) {
  con.query("SELECT "+lang+" FROM content", function(err,result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (result.length > 0) {
      return callback(result);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
}

getContent(l, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I want to assign data in the second function.

Answer (score 0):

this should done ..

```
getContent = function (lang, callback) => {
    con.query("SELECT "+lang+" FROM content", function(err,result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (result.length > 0) {
            callback(result);
        } else {
            callback(false);
        }
    });
};

getContent(l, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Hi, it says - SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>

Comment: remove function keyword and try once again